# LineChartData to BarChartData

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I get the problem from xcode:

Could not cast value of type 'Charts.LineChartData' (0x1037def20) to 'Charts.BarChartData' (0x1037e89c0).

```
private func setLineStats(data: [Int],when: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<data.count {
        dataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry(value: Double(data[i]), xIndex: i))
    }
    let lineDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Function calls")
    let lineData = LineChartData(xVals: self.months, dataSets: lineDataSet)
    lineChartView.data = lineData
}
```

I used this as a dummy code to ensure that any object using BarChart.

```
private func setBarStats(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    lineChartView.data = chartData
}
```

Comment: Did you use `as! BarChartData` ?

Comment: Where? Not in any my written class as I know off.

Comment: In BarChartView class from the API, there is the `as! BarChartData`

Comment: This is where the app crashed. You shouldn't force-cast `LineChartData` to `BarChartData`

Comment: How should it be then? Setting it to `as? BarChartData` causes crash where the variable is in use. 
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem were in the Storyboard where the View that being used was set to BarChartView. Changed to LineChartView and it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You confused with how to use `Optional` and `as`. First, `Optional` means this maybe nil. `as` used for type-cast. `as?` means I want to get an optional new type variable. So you may get nil from this. `as!` means I'm sure it's not nil or I want to crash it when get nil. Here is [WWDC Swift Optional Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/401/)

Comment: The error refers to the API class which I think is not a good idea to edit that.

Comment: Shaize. The problem were in Storyboard where I had the View set to BarChartView class.